# Highcharts: Fade plotLines based on hover on marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a scatter chart with a series. Some of the observations have corresponding limit values, which I have added as PlotLines. Say there are 2 unique PlotLines, and each scatter observation only belongs to one of them. As an added complication, there are multiple scatter series, so this has to work with all of them.

If there are 2 plotLines on the graph, upon the user hovering over one of the scatter points of any series, I only want the plotLine that belongs to that point to stay visible, and the others to fade.

I know this is a lot to ask for and may not be possible. I've started fiddling with this, from an example I found here: [Highcharts: Add plotlines based on enabled series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130095/highcharts-add-plotlines-based-on-enabled-series). I've modified the fiddle towards my problem, showing 2 data series, and the data in the 'plotline' variable indicating a 1 or 2. I don't know how to link this data to the plotLines though, and make them fade as explained.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nghfemb/1/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    plotLines: [{
        value: 50.5,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plot-line-1'
    },{
        value: 130.5,
        color: 'blue',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plot-line-2'
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    events: {
      show: function() {
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
          value: 50.5,
          color: 'red',
          width: 2,
          id: 'plot-line-1'
        });
      },
      hide: function() {
        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1')
      }
    },
    data: [
    {
        y: 29.9, 
        plotline: 1
    }, {
        y: 71.5,
      plotline: 2
    }, {
      y: 106.4,
      plotline: 1
    }, {
        y: 129.2,
      plotline: 1
    }],
    type: 'scatter'
  },
    {
    data: [
    {
        y: 145.9, 
        plotline: 2
    }, {
        y: 111.5,
      plotline: 2
    }, {
      y: 167.4,
      plotline: 1
    }, {
        y: 101.2,
      plotline: 2
    }],
    type: 'scatter'
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to show or hide the plot lines:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                    var plotLines = this.series.yAxis.plotLinesAndBands;

                    plotLines.forEach(function(el, i) {
                        if (i === this.plotline - 1) {
                            el.svgElem.show();
                        } else {
                            el.svgElem.hide();
                        }
                    }, this);
                },

            }
        },
        events: {
            mouseOut: function() {
                var plotLines = this.yAxis.plotLinesAndBands;

                plotLines[0].svgElem.show();
                plotLines[1].svgElem.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vh1z97yr/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#show

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

Comment: Thank you, that works great for me. It does not however, also hide the plotLine labels. Is this easily possible as well? I'm assuming as this is not an SVG element, it needs its own reference in the for loop.

Comment: Hi @John Hekman, Yes, you can hide or show the labels in a very similar way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hurefvta/